# Appinvite_styles.xml:5: error When including Google Play Services library to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, styles, admob, google-play-services

I need to add an ad to my application. So I need to include Google Play Services library to my project. I have installed lastest version of Google Play Services (r29) and added to my projects as libProject. But when I add this service lib I'm getting error below:

```
workspace\Google_Play_Services_Lib\res\values-v21\appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
```

How can I solve this problem ? Thanks for help..

Comment: me too just right now. A bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just changed Project SDK to 20 (from 21) and all compiled.

Comment: I changed project build target from Project -> Properties -> Android to API 20 but nothing changed. Where I'm wrong =)

Comment: check modules SDK less 21 too.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by checking the **Is Library** option and I referenced appcompat_v7

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem, but now it's been resolved. Below are the steps I followed
- Go to project properties->Android
- Under 'Project Build Target', select Android 5.0.1. Press and clean the library project.